# Posting Unicode Characters to Apigee

Tags: objective-c, xcode, apigee

When sending unicode characters Apigee seems to deny these.

The values are entered into the NSDictionary okay using the code below:

```
NSMutableDictionary *entity = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init ];
textView.text = @"È ê ü à ã"
NSString *message = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:[textView.text cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

[entity setObject:@"messages" forKey:@"type"];
[entity setObject:message forKey:@"message"];

AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[ [UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
ApigeeClientResponse *response = [appDelegate.dataClient createEntity:entity];
```

If I NSLog the NSDictionary I see:

```
{
    type = messages;
    message = "\U00c8 \U00ea \U00fc \U00e0 \U00e3";
}
```

After posting this to Apigee, the success response returns without the special characters:

```
{
    type = messages;
    message = "E e u a a";
}
```

How to I prevent the NSDictionary from encoding these characters and allowing the Unicode characters to save into Apigee?

Comment: As many have done before, you are confusing the output of NSLog with the contents of the dictionary. NSLog outputs ASCII characters only and displays non-Unicode characters the way it likes.

Comment: If I NSLog `entity[@"message"]` I get returned `"È ê ü à ã"` but NSLog the whole dictionary returns `"\U00c8 \U00ea \U00fc \U00e0 \U00e3"`. I get a response returned from Apigee after posting I see `"E e u a a"` so I am unsure where these characters are changed disregarding the NSLog.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue was resolved within the newest Apigee version 2.0.14.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried testing this with something more straightforward like cURL?  Just to make sure it isn't a problem with the iOS SDK?  In other words, if you still see the problem with cURL, then it would be a problem with the server-side stack.  If you don't see the problem, then it is the SDK.

Comment: I thought about this. The response that was stored is: `message = \"\\U00c8 \\U00e1 \\U00fc \\U00fb\"; type = messages;` so i'd assume the NSDictionary is changing the format of the characters and not storing is as `"È ê ü à ã"` like I hoped it would.